# Need help fixing strange template error

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

When I try to compile my project I get a C2440 error saying `'initializing' : cannot convert from 'vector<component_count>' to 'vector_2D'.` The MSDN documentation on C2440 says `The compiler cannot cast from 'type1' to 'type2'.` I have a base class, vector:

```
template <unsigned int component_count>
class vector {...}
```

and a derived class, vector_2D:

```
class vector_2D : public vector<2>
```

My base class defines a default and copy constructor, and operator overloads. The code which gives me the error is:

```
vector_2D character_position = pen_position + vector_2D(offset_x, offset_y);
```

pen_position is created earlier as

```
vector_2D pen_position(string_position);
```

I can't seem to fix my error. Can anyone point out what is going wrong and/or how to fix it?

Comment: What is the prototype for your `operator+` overload?

Comment: How is your `operator+` declared/defined?

Comment: It is: vector operator + (const vector& a_vector) const

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector operator + (const vector& a_vector) const
```

is the problem. You're returning a base and then trying to assign it to the derived.

The simplest fix is to provide an overload

```
vector_2D operator + (const vector_2D& a_vector) const
```

Comment: If I wanted to avoid redefining the operator completely, would I be able to call the base class addition operator from the derived class operator and cast the returned base down to the derived again? If not I guess I'll just define vector_2D, vector_3D, and vector_4D separately without using inheritance.

Comment: @Cole you can do it with some sort of tag dispatched templates but it is more complicated.

Comment: Alright, I guess I'll remove the inheritance. Thanks for the answer and comment!